# How to send Email notification for Agent level failure azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I'm working in the Azure Devops pipeline. how to send the email notification in case of agent level failure. In Single Pipeline multiple agent configured.
I can get the notification only we Build Failed and completed.
Need to get the notification once the agent failed no need to wait for until pipeline complete.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, [Azure DevOps Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/oob-built-in-notifications?view=azure-devops#supported-subscriptions) are pre-defined and don't support customized, so I am afraid that Azure DevOps notifications cannot meet your requirement.
[image]

In addition, as a workaround we can use the free popular 3rd-party extension: [Send Email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask), which supports to configure body and add attachment. Thus you could add the `Send email` task as the last step of agent job and set `eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Failed')` to be its run condition, so this task will send agent failed notification when this agent job is failed. See: [Job status check functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-status-functions) for more details.
[image]

Comment: Hi prathiyag, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, I tried your solution and it gave me the below error in the Agent log-
Evaluating: eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Failed')
Expanded: eq('SucceededWithIssues', 'Failed')
Result: False

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi Sayali, you could follow this ```in(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Failed')``` to evaluate the job result. See: [Job status check functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-status-functions) for more details.

Comment: Only works for windows agents